# How to change the images on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the image by pressing the button.I have two button, one is next and other is previous.When the next button press new image must be shown and previous button press last image should come agian.But I can't do this properly.How to do this using jquery?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#image2').hide();
$('#image3').hide();
$(".arrow").click(function () {
        $('#image1').hide();
        $('#image2').show();
    });
});
```

Html is

```
<div class="imageDiv">
   <div><img src="potraits.jpg" class="image" id="image1"/></div>
   <div><img src="pot.jpg" class="image" id="image2"/></div>
   <div><img src="potri.jpg" class="image" id="image3"/></div>
   <div><input type="image" src="arrow.gif" class="arrow"/></div>
   <div><input type="image" src="leftarrow.gif" class="leftarrow"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: best solution would be to keep the images as numbered,eg :image1,image2......etc., when writing logic in jquery, just contruct the image name each time, when next is clicked increment the value of index and on previous reverse.`var img="image"; var index=0; var imgName= img+ index;`

Comment: using the above logic you can contruct the div container dynamically, no need for hide functions. **Write Less Do More**

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/S6t9R/1/ there is no looparound, you can add it.

Comment: @user2264587-But I have only one one button to show these three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/S6t9R/4/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img:not(:first)').hide();
    $(".arrow").click(function () {
        $('img:not(:last):visible').
        hide().
        parent().
        next().
        children().
        show();
    });
    $(".leftarrow").click(function () {
        $('img:not(:first):visible').
        hide().
        parent().
        prev().
        children().
        show();
    });
});
```

basically, the image that is visible is now hidden, and the next/previous image is now visible.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the image src?

JavaScript:

```
var images = [
    "alpha.jpg",
    "beta.jpg",
    "gamma.jpg"
];
var actImg = 0; // index of actual image

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".leftarrow").click(function () {
        if (actImg <= 0) { // if first image is displayed, jump to last
            actImg = images.length - 1;
        }
        else {
            actImg--;
        }
        $('#onlyimage').attr('src', images[actImg]);
    });
    $(".rightarrow").click(function () {
        if (images.length <= actImg) { // if last image is displayed, jump to first
            actImg = 0;
        }
        else {
            actImg++;
        }
        $('#onlyimage').attr('src', images[actImg]);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="imageDiv">
    <div><img src="alpha.jpg" class="image" id="onlyimage"/></div>
    <div><input type="image" src="leftarrow.gif" class="leftarrow"/></div>
    <div><input type="image" src="rightarrow.gif" class="rightarrow"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated the my answer, you can define 3 or more images, and iterate through them with the arrows.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in this case you could hide/show the div-elements around your images. If you hide an image the way you do, the div itself will still be 'visible' in the document, which is probably what gives you the unwanted result.

Answer (score 0):

```
Change your script,

 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#secondimage').hide();
  $('#thirdimage').hide();
 $(".arrow").click(function () {
    $('#firstimage').hide();
    $('#secondimage').show();
  });
$(".leftarrow").click(function () {
    $('#firstimage').show();
    $('#secondimage').hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    that = this;
    this.arrayImages = $('.image');
    this.currentPosition = 0;
    $('#secondimage').hide();
    $('#thirdimage').hide();
    $(".arrow").click(function () {
        if (that.currentPosition < that.arrayImages.length) {
            that.arrayImages[that.currentPosition].hide();
            that.arrayImages[that.currentPosition+1].show();
            that.currentPosition++;
        }
    });
});
```

For the leftarrow it's just the other way (: