# How to show different links when certain questions are answered

Tags: javascript, html

How do I make it so that when I click AT&T, 8GB, and Black it shows a link and when I click Other, 8GB, and White it shows a different link. This is what I came up with. This is my first ever attempt so don't be rough on me. I'm trying to achieve something similar to http://glyde.com/sell/iphone-4s.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.bgclr {background-color: white; color: black; font-weight: bold;}
-->
</style>


<script language="JavaScript">

<!-- Begin
var numQues = 3;

var numChoi = 3;

var answers = new Array(3);

// Do not change anything below here ...
function getScore(form) {
var score = 0;
var currElt;
var currSelection;
for (i=0; i<numQues; i++) {
currElt = i*numChoi;
for (j=0; j<numChoi; j++) {
  currSelection = form.elements[currElt + j];
  if (currSelection.checked) {
    if (currSelection.value == answers[i]) {
      score++;
      break;
    }
  }
}
}
</script>


</head>

<body>


<form name="quiz">

What carrier do you have?
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
  <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="AT&T"/>AT&T</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Other"/>Other</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Unlocked"/>Unlocked</li>
</ul>

What is your phones capicity?
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
  <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="8GB"/>8GB</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="16GB"/>16GB</li>
</ul>

What color is your phone?
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
  <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="Black"/>Black</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="White"/>White</li>
</ul>


<input type="button" value="Get score" onClick="getScore(this.form)"/>


</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/2547/

Comment: what do you mean by 'it shows a different link'? Do you mean, you want a link to automatically appear, or do you mean you want "get score" to take them to some where else, or do you mean something else?

Comment: @SethCohen No I mean that if a user chooses 3 answers and another user chooses 3 different answers they both get different links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Add an "onclick" event to each element of the form, which calls a method called tryToMakeLink(). So for every element

```
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="AT&T"/>
```

should now read

```
<input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q1" value="AT&T"/>
```

Also, add a div to the bottom to display the dynamic link.

```
<form name="quiz" id='quiz'>

    What carrier do you have?
    <ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
        <li><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q1" value="AT&T"/>AT&T</li>
        <li><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q1" value="Other"/>Other</li>
        <li><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q1" value="Unlocked"/>Unlocked</li>
    </ul>

    What is your phones capicity?
    <ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
        <li><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q2" value="8GB"/>8GB</li>
        <li><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q2" value="16GB"/>16GB</li>
    </ul>

    What color is your phone?
    <ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
        <li><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q3" value="Black"/>Black</li>
        <li><input type="radio" onclick=tryToMakeLink(); name="q3" value="White"/>White</li>
    </ul>


    <input type="button" value="Get score" onClick="getScore(this.form)"/>
    <br>
    <div id=linkDiv>
        --
    </div>
</form>
```

The `tryToMakeLink()` method does the following:

Look at each radio. If the user has not made a choice for each question, do nothing.
If the user has made a choice for each question, then show 1 link if they have 8gb at&t black, show another link if they have other 8gb white, show a 3rd link if they have any other combination. you can easily add other configurations by adding more `else if` clauses to the function.

So here it is (JavaScript)

```
    function tryToMakeLink()
    {
        //get all selected radios
        var q1=document.querySelector('input[name="q1"]:checked');
        var q2=document.querySelector('input[name="q2"]:checked');
        var q3=document.querySelector('input[name="q3"]:checked');
        //make sure the user has selected all 3
        if (q1==null || q2==null ||q3==null)
        {
            document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="--";
        }
        else
        {
            //now we know we have 3 radios, so get their values
            q1=q1.value;
            q2=q2.value;
            q3=q3.value;
            //now check the values to display a different link for the desired configuration
            if (q1=="AT&T" && q2=="8GB" && q3=="Black")
            {
                document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<a href=#>att 8gb black</a>";
            }
            else if (q1=="Other" && q2=="8GB" && q3=="White")
            {
                document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<a href=#>other 8b white</a>";
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<a href=#>some third option</a>";
            }
        }
    }
```

This is all javascript, as indicated by your post; however you may want to look into jQuery.

EDIT:
A better way to do this is to bind the click event to each radio when the document loads, instead of needing an "onclick=" in each input tag.

so you add an onload to your body

```
<body onLoad="attachClickEvents();">
```

and add this javascript

```
        function attachClickEvents()
        {

            var inputs=document.getElementById('quiz').elements;
            for (var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++)
            {
                inputs[i].onclick = function() {
                    tryToMakeLink();
                };
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are so amazing. I can't thank you anymore. You've saved so many pages for my website.

Comment: glad to help! also check out my edit about binding, that way, you do not need to put "onclick=tryToMakeLink();" into each radio button.

Comment: Is there anyway I could add a button to that? If so can it be light and unclickable until all questions are answered and it the button is then clickable and the button lights up to it's original color?

Comment: Yeah in the if that checks for nullity, instead of "--" make innerHTML something like `<input type=button disabled=disabled value=Next>` then in the subsequent ifs that make the link they should be something like `<input type=button value=Next onclick="window.location.href='/your/url/';">`

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work. Here's what I put in every else if's -----------

'else if (q1=="AT&T" && q2=="16GB" && q3=="White")
            {
document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<input type=button value=Next onclick="window.location.href='http://bing.com/';">another option</input>";
            }'
---------
I put this in the place of the 3 dashes '<input type=button disabled=disabled value=Next>'

Comment: escape your quotes my good sir.
`document.getElementById("linkDiv").innerHTML="<input type=button value=Next onclick=\"window.location.href='bing.com/';\">another option</input>";

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36187/discussion-between-user2680614-and-seth-cohen)

Answer (score -1):

I think that this could help you!

[How to change the images on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055253/how-to-change-the-images-on-button-click)

It is another SO question that I found useful for the same thing!